# Display three dots (ellipsis) in case of text overflow

Tags: html, css

I would like to display an ellipsis if text goes overflows in single line within its container.  Is there a CSS property that I have to apply to do so?

Answer (score 6):

Apply the below CSS3 property

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this for your element: 
`text-overflow: ellipsis;`

You'll also have to declare the `overflow: hidden;` so that the browser knows to limit the dimensions of your text to the container size (and subsquently where to start the *text-overflow* behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following class to the text that you want to truncate and add ellipsis' to.

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

DEMO here

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow